# AnyEvent::Socket and abstract UNIX socket

Tags: perl, anyevent

With Socket i can use:

```
socket(my $socket, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    or die "socket: $!";
my $sock_addr = sockaddr_un(chr(0).'/abstract/socket');
connect($socket, $sock_addr)  or die "connect: $!";
```

all ok. i connect and can transmit/receive;

With AnyEvent::Socket:

```
tcp_connect "unix/",chr(0).'/abstract/socket' , sub {
    my ($fh) = @_
        or die "unable to connect: $!";
    ...
}
```

and get error: `unable to connect: No such device or address at file.pl line X.`

How to use abstract UNIX sockets with Anyevent::Socket?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I dug into this one a bit, the short answer is that AnyEvent::Socket doesnt support abstract sockets.

The Longer answer is that it really should, and as far as I can see its a small oversight preventing it from working.

The sub `resolve_sockaddr` is the culprit, line 718 in my version:

```
   if ($node eq "unix/") {
      return $cb->() if $family || $service !~ /^\//; # no can do

      return $cb->([AF_UNIX, defined $type ? $type : SOCK_STREAM, 0, Socket::pack_sockaddr_un $service]);
   }
```

The part of the line which reads `$service !~ /^\//; # no can do` is what is preventing it from working.

In my case I just commented out that line, and it worked, but really the regex should be modified to allow for `\0` at the front to denote the abstract socket path.

You have a few options:

- Modify your local copy of the library
- Push the change upstream to Marc Lehmann and hope he accepts a patch
- Monkey patch the function
- Implement your own module which supports abstract domain sockets

Good luck.